# Skype for Business Server 2015 - Prepare Active Directory fails with error: 5

Tags: lync, skype-for-business-2016

I am trying to deploy Skype for Business 2015 to a test lab following [this guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn951386.aspx). I have performed all prerequisite actions up to Prepare Active Directory. when I run the task to prepare the AD schema from the Deployment Wizard it fails with the following error message in the log.

```
Error: Upload C:\Program Files\Skype for Business Server 2015\Deployment\Setup\ExternalSchema.ldf failed. The exit code is "5".
▼ Details
└ Type: DeploymentException
    └ ▼ Stack Trace
    └   at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Deployment.LcSchema.ThrowLDIFDE_ErrorCodeDeploymentException(String path, Int32 exitCode) 
        at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Deployment.LcSchema.UploadSchema(String path) 
        at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Deployment.LcSchema.PrepareSchema(String ldf, SchemaType schemaType) 
        at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Deployment.Tasks.ServerSchemaPrepareTask.Action()
```

I can confirm I am running as a member of the *Schema Admins* group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this was a permissions error. Although my user was a member of the *Schema Admins* group I had not signed out / back in since adding the user to the group. Doing so fixed the issue.